# Turning a formula containing Loop, if or and else to VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Two formulas have been giving me a lot of trouble. I used to manually insert the formula in the first row, column and then copy and paste it into all the columns. Here are two formulas
For

`Column A: =(IF(C2="","",IF(LEFT(C2,3)="Bus","BU CRM","CSI ACE")))`

```
Column B:  =IF(C2="","",IF(LEFT(C2,3)="CSI", "",RIGHT(C2,LEN(C2)-14)))
```

Here are my attempts

Column A:

```
`FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For m = 1 To FinalRow
If Cells.Left(m, 3) = Bus Then Cells(m, 1) = "BU CRM" Else Cells(m, 1) = "CSI ACE"
Next m
End If`
```

Column B:

```
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For J = 1 To FinalRow

If Cells(J, 3) = "" Or Cells.Left(J, 3) = "CSI" _
Then Cells(J, 2) = "" _
Else Cells(J, 2) = Right.(Cells(J, 3) - 14) _

Next J

End If
```

Essentially my code for column A to look at column C, and if the cell in column C first 3 letters are "Bus" then Column A should be "BU CRM" otherwise it should be "CSI ACE"

Whereas, column B is supposed to look at column C and if the cell in column C starts with "CSI" it should return in Column B "". If column C does not start with "CS", return the last 14 letters/numbers into Column B.

I hope I have clarified my problem and Question.

Comment: Are there like thousands of rows? a few? I mean there could be 2 approaches, working on the seet (not a lot of rows) or working with arrays, when your data is huge

Comment: Hey Damian, sadly it's sounds of rows. Around 65,000. I would have used a different method, but I'm short with time and that's what's needed currently. Would you kindly assist me in the code?

Comment: I'm gonna change your code all the way, gonna show you how to do it with arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with lots of data may tax your procedure if done on the worksheet, the way to go is filling an array with all the data and then changing everything in it to lastly paste it back to the sheet. This is how:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillColumns()

    Dim arrData As Variant, LastRow As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change the name of the sheet to the one you are doing the code

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrData)
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "Bus*" Then
                arrData(i, 1) = "BU CRM"
            Else
                arrData(i, 1) = "CSI ACE"
            End If
            If arrData(i, 3) Like "CSI*" Or arrData(i, 3) = vbNullString Then
                arrData(i, 2) = vbNullString
            Else
                arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), 14)
            End If
        Next i
        .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, "C")).Value = arrData
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Damian, I'm not too familiar with Array's what so ever. I did attempt on copying and pasting your code. It did work on column A, for one row. Whereas Column B showed no difference.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Search for them, but they are for storing things inside the computer's memory where all your calculations are insanely faster than doing them on the sheet. Did you try the code?

Comment: Optimisation or making the code faster is sadly not the goal but rather to make it as "user friendly" as possible.

Comment: What do you mean? User friendly for you?

Comment: The goal was to make it so that by a click of a command button that this code would run. User friendly to the average person with no background in VBA

Comment: You just link a command button to this macro and that's what it will do... but faster than your first thought.

Comment: I have with no success, the first A2 was filled but nothing else did.

Comment: That's entierly my fault sorry, I've copied ur code to get the last row and I assume column A is empty. On the lastrow variable, change the 1 for a 3

Comment: I truly can't thank you enough, last point is Column B, it does not seem to work. I change the code as you suggested for the lastrow: it worked for column A but not B

Comment: change the `arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 2), 14)` for `arrData(i, 2) = Right(arrData(i, 3), 14)` an oversight on your code, sorry.

Comment: It has worked thank you a ton. I really appreciate all your help :)

Comment: No problem :) don't forget to mark it as answer if it helped so others can find it.